# Downloaded images do not get saved in phone gallery phonegap cordova

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have got an issue when trying to save an image from a URL to phone gallery.

**savetoImageGallery.js**

```
window.requestFileSystem(window.LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, onError);

function onSuccess(fileSystem) {

  var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root; 

  var name = imageName.split('/').pop();
  var imageUrl = encodeURI(decodeURIComponent(AppSettings.baseApiUrl + imageName));

  var fp = fileSystem.root.toURL();
  var filepath = fp + name;
  var ft = new window.FileTransfer();
  var f =  ft.download(imageUrl, filepath,
    function (entry) {
      console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log("download error target " + error.target);
    }
  );
}
```

The image gets downloaded correctly from the url but it gets saved to the root of the file directory but doesnt show in the phone gallery.

How do i solve this issue ? I am using cordova.

Answer (score 1):

**The next answer only applies for Android and for the latest version of the file-transfer plugin:**

I had a similar problem with my app, and the reason was it was saving the image on a subfolder inside my package folder:

```
file:///data/data/<package-name>/files/files
```

(That folder wasn't found later by the gallery).

To solve this problem you have to add the next line on your config.xml:

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

This is due to some changes they had made to the plugin. More info:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file (Under "Android Quirks")

Now, there's another problem, and it's that the gallery needs to read again the SDCard to be able to display the images, so after downloading the image you need to find a way to read again the memory and then you'll be able to see your images. To test if this is your problem, after downloading the image restart yout phone so it will read the file system again, and then check your gallery.

To solve that problem you'll have to write your own plugin, or you can use one that has already been done (remember to check OS compatibility) like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-refresh-gallery

Hope this helps.

Cheers!